# Find maximum of 'jsonb_path_query_array' output

Tags: postgresql, max, jsonb

I'm using postgres with a jsonb field that looks something like this:

```
{[[1.2, 'blah'], [3.4, 'blahhh']}
```

I'm extracting the numbers by using:

```
jsonb_path_query_array(json_row, '$[*][0]')
```

Which gives the `jsonb` object `[1.2, 3.4]`. I'm now trying to find the maximum of this array to no avail. I've tried using `jsonb_array_elements`, but this seems only to somehow truncate the array, returning a single element.

So, how can I get the maximum of a `jsonb` array? preferably, this would be done without the use of a subquery.

Comment: try this `SELECT max(val::numeric)
FROM jsonb_array_elements_text(
    jsonb_path_query_array(json_row, '$[*][0]')
) AS val;`

Comment: @KinShah Thanks! but I'd like the jsonb_path_query_array to be in the select, since I'm trying to select other fields as well from the table.